# Getting Product info in Element Block (Volusion)

Tags: volusion

I'm trying to create a custom block to add some info into a product page on the Volusion platform. I have looked through the documentation, but haven't managed to find anything conclusive.

Is there a way to get the product id/slug/name automagically upon page load?

Answer (score 1):

On the productDetails.asp page (when you view a product), you have access to the productCode in JS via this variable  global_Current_ProductCode.